# DjangoのDBで、モデルクラスを利用することなく、実行したSQLを取得する方法

Tags: python3, django, sqlite

Djangoに搭載されているデータベースクライアント(ORマッパー)の機能で、
実行したSQL文字列を取得することは可能でしょうか？
パラメータが埋め込まれたSQL文をログ出力するために、利用したいと考えています。

下記の例では、
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id='A001';
のように、Where句のパラメータが埋め込まれたものを取得したいです。

```
# Djangoのインストール
# !pip3 install --upgrade django

from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # テーブルの作成
    cursor.execute(sql='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;')
    cursor.execute(sql='CREATE TABLE test_table(id integer, name text);')
    # データの追加
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO test_table(id, name) VALUES("A001", "apple");')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO test_table(id, name) VALUES("A002", "banana");')

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # データの検索
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id=%s;', params=['A001'])
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])

print('SQL')  # <---ここで直前に実行したSQL文(SELECT文)をログ出力したい。
```

実行結果

```
A001 apple
```

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet.query を文字列化することでSQLが得られます(A)。
ログ出力という観点では、Django標準の機能を使う方法もあります(B)。

A. ORMのQuerySetオブジェクトを文字列化する

```py
qs = User.objects.all()
print(str(qs.query))
```

A2. Aの文字列を読みやすくフォーマットする

```py
qs = User.objects.all()
query = qs.query

from sqlparse import format as sfmt
print(sfmt(str(query), reindent_aligned=True))
```

B. DjangoのLOGGINGを設定する

`settings.py`

```py
LOGGING = {
    ...
    "loggers": {
        "django.db.backends": {
            "handlers": [...],
            "level": "DEBUG",  # デフォルトはERRORのみログ出力
            "propagate": False,
        },
```

参考

- [ロギング | Django ドキュメント | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/4.2/ref/logging/#django-db-backends)
- [逆引きDjangoORM: ORMで生成されるSQLを確認したい - 清水川のScrapbox](https://scrapbox.io/shimizukawa/%E9%80%86%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8DDjangoORM:_ORM%E3%81%A7%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8BSQL%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#6284794d1911970000d89d22)
- [Django + gunicorn のログ出力設定 - 清水川のScrapbox](https://scrapbox.io/shimizukawa/Django_+_gunicorn_%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)
- [60:Django ORMでどんなSQLが発行されているか気にしよう — 自走プログラマー【抜粋版】](https://jisou-programmer.beproud.jp/DjangoORM%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E5%90%88%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9/60-Django_ORM%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%AASQL%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86.html)
- [【第17回】Django ORM道場 ……クエリの基本を押さえ，より良い型を身に付けよう - WEB+DB PRESS Vol.133｜技術評論社](https://gihyo.jp/magazine/wdpress/archive/2023/vol133)

Comment: ありがとうございます。(B)の方法はできました。
(A)の方法は、自作のUserクラス(ORマッパーのUserモデル)を作成するということでしょうか？
Userクラスを作成せずに、実行したSQL文を取得することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: Aの方法は、任意のモデルクラスでできる方法です。自動ではなく、SQLがほしいときに自分で書く必要があります。

Comment: 少なくとも一つ以上の、任意のモデルクラスを作成しなければならないこと、わかりました。ありがとうございます。